Jointmarket Tumbler / yield_generator issue
I am unable to get the joinmarket tumbler or yield generator scripts working.
In particular the script enters a loop, trying to connect to .onion sites before dropping out and showing:
[ERROR]  We failed to connect and handshake with ANY directories; onion messaging is not functioning.

The sendpayment script on the other hand works fine (despite also giving the above error).
I am running joinmarket on an arch machine with tor and bitcoin core both running locally.
Software versions:
joinmarket-clientserver-0.9.11
bitcoin-26.0
Tor 0.4.8.12

I thought it might be an issue of incoming tor connections but the node accepts connections (in and out) over tor.
bitcoin-cli -netinfo
         ipv4    ipv6   onion   total   block
in         43       0       6      49
out         3       2       5      10       2
total      46       2      11      59

I thought it might be an issue with SOCKS proxy but netstat suggests correct functioning.
netstat -tuln | grep 9050
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Similarly curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 https://check.torproject.org suggests connection is successfully made over tor.
I have tried both with and without cookie / password authentication. Neither seems to make a difference.
My Torrc config:
ControlPort 9051
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 8333 127.0.0.1:8333

My Joinmarket config:
[MESSAGING:onion]
# onion based message channels must have the exact type 'onion'
# (while the section name above can be MESSAGING:whatever), and there must
# be only ONE such message channel configured (note the directory servers
# can be multiple, below):
type = onion

socks5_host = localhost
socks5_port = 9050

tor_control_host = localhost
tor_control_port = 9051
onion_serving_host = 127.0.0.1
onion_serving_port = 8333


[MESSAGING:server1]
channel = joinmarket-pit
port = 6697
usessl = true


# For Tor (recommended as clearnet alternative):
host = <xyz>.onion
socks5 = true
socks5_host = localhost
socks5_port = 9050

## IRC SERVER 2: ILITA IRC (optional IRC alternate, Tor only)
################################################################################
[MESSAGING:server2]
channel = joinmarket-pit
port = 6667
usessl = false
socks5 = true
socks5_host = localhost

host = <xyz>.onion
socks5_port = 9050

My bitcoin config:
server=1
listen=1

## TOR PARAMS
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
 
# set the control port to access tor
torcontrol=127.0.0.1:9051
torpassword='<my_password>' 

Note, the tor ControlPort 9051 is working successfully as am able to connect to the tor relay using nyx to confirm in and outbound traffic.
Very puzzled by this issue. Help very much appreciated.

Have you tried adding the additional directory nodes from https://github.com/JoinMarket-Org/joinmarket-clientserver/issues/1445? I believe the default list doesn't have great uptime

Thanks for suggestion. Will add proposed nodes and re-test.

Update: adding the additional directory nodes does not appear to make a difference.
I am wondering whether the issue might be related to establishing a connection to my hidden service. Am getting the [INFO] output 'We, NOT-SERVING-ONION, are calling the handshake callback as client'
